# How to apply style to button in the file input

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to use file input in my code in MAC the alignment looks bad. In all remaining, it looks fine. I can't able to apply a style to the only button(Choose file) when I am trying to apply the style is applied to the text(No file chosen) also.

In MAC:

[image]

in other laptops:

[image]

CSS:

```
input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: When you say “MAC” do you mean the Mac OS operating system? If so is it *just* Mac OS, or iOS as well? Is it all browsers, or just Safari? And why are we - apparently - shouting OS names?

Comment: This is probably a browser issue .Which version of Safari does your MAC have? Download chrome/firefox to see that it is indeed a browser issue. Also add the minimal HTML code for the field so we can reproduce.

Comment: yes, @David Thomas it is in "Mac" os. we are using chrome as browser

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <label for="pickerId">
       Your custom picker viewable item to be added here and style to be applied to this label. The real input will be hidden but clicking here will be enough to trigger file picker
    </label>
    <input id="pickerId" style="display:none;" type="file"/>
```